# Combine Different Metrics to CausalImpact

Tags: python, causality, causalimpact, bsts

I am currently trying to understand the Google package of [CausalImpact](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html), to be more concrete the [python implementation](https://github.com/dafiti/causalimpact).

My current state is that I have for example the sales of a car on different markets (`A`, `B` and `C`) per day, like

```
Day   A   B   C 
1     12  43  16
2     19  39  10
3     11  20  19 
..    ..  ..  ..
```

I can use the information from `B` and `C` to model the behaviour of `A` for a certain post period.

But, (how) can I include more, different data types in here? For example, I don't only include sales, but other data like customers (`C_n`) per day, or search queries per day.

```
Day   A   B   C    C_a   C_b   C_c
1     12  43  16   1022  1283  1234
2     19  39  10   3642  2746  2846
3     11  20  19   2746  2846  2547
..    ..  ..  ..   ..    ..    ..
```

As, for example the views would be way higher than the sales, the data would be distorted. So, my first approach here was to norm the data, based on the input group, to a scale between 0 and 1, like

```
Day   A    B    C     C_a  C_b  C_c
1     0.2  0.6  0.2   0.3  0.1  0.2
2     0.3  0.9  0.3   0.8  0.2  0.4
3     0.2  0.5  0.5   0.9  0.6  0.6
..    ..   ..   ..    ..   ..   ..
```

Still, I don't know if this is the right way to go, as I mix several metrics within an estimation. Therefore, is there a better (**any?**) way on how to use different metrics for one CausalImpact model?